# remotely log out of (graphical) gnome session

Tags: gnome, ssh, logout, gnome-session

I have a (graphical) login session running on an office computer, and I'd like to log it out to save on a few computer resources.

I can ssh to the office box, but when I try `gnome-session-quit` I get this:

```
$ gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt

** (gnome-session-quit:18500): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=fca99a51622d1930b068883b00000005 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n

** (gnome-session-quit:18500): WARNING **: Unable to start: Cannot open display:
```

Makes sense as my `$DISPLAY` is empty (as it's a headless ssh session). When I run `w`, I see that the `gnome-session` is running on `tty7`. Is there a way I can pretend to be `tty7` and initiate a logout? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Usually with `w`, I see some line to this effect:
`muru  :0        Wed20   ?xdm?  11:15m  1.10s gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-password]`, the `:0` being my relevant `$DISPLAY`. Don't you? You can also try `pgrep -fa X` and see what X is running with.

Comment: the entry from `w` with `gnome-session` had `tty7` as the display, but the session had several other entries with `:0` (terminals open I guess?). Checking the time column from `w` I realised `:0` was the graphical session for sure (:

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After logging in with `ssh`, run:

```
env DISPLAY=:0.0 gnome-session-quit --logout
```

This will force a logout on the remote machine just as if you had logged out from the menu (but without prompting).  You may need to run [`gnome-session-quit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gnome-session-quit) with `--force-logout` if there's an application with, for example, unsaved work, that would otherwise prevent a clean logout.

If you use a very old version (<2011) of GNOME, then you need to

```
env DISPLAY=:0.0 gnome-session-save --logout
```

[... because `gnome-session-save` was renamed to `gnome-session-quit` in 2011.](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2011-February/msg00147.html)

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/191155/remotely-log-off-same-user-on-a-server)

Comment: On the office box, there is no `gnome-session-save`, but there is a `gnome-session-quit` which (with the rest of your answer) did the trick. I forgot to mention it's running Ubuntu 12.04 - perhaps that's why?

Comment: @drevicko probably a typo. It's still `-quit` on a 12.04 box I have.

Comment: gnome-session-save was renamed to gnome-session-quit in 2011: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2011-February/msg00147.html

Comment: @muru: updated answer accordingly

Comment: Note that if the session is run under a session manager like Xvnc, it may not be on display 0.0. You can often find the display by doing a `ps ux` listing to find the process and see which display number is listed with the process. For example, my Xvnc process was listed as `Xvnc :10 -geometry...`, so I had to use `env DISPLAY=:10.0 ...`.